# "message": "Unauthorized/Not token"

Tags: nodejs, express, jwt, cookies

¡Hola! Hice un backen con Node js, Express, Mongoose, JsonEbToken y estoy experimentando un problema al hacer peticiones desde Thunder Client después de agregar Swagger para documentar tu backend. Aunque las peticiones funcionan desde Swagger, cuando las realizo desde Thunder Client, el token en la cookie llega como undefined, causando que la petición sea rechazada al verificar el token. ¿alguien puede ayudarme a solucionar este problema? tener en cuenta que desde Swagger si ingresa la peticion con un token

```js
const createAccesToken = (payload) => {
    console.log(payload);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jwt.sign(
            payload,
            TOKEN_SECRET,
            { expiresIn: "1d" },
            (error, token) => {
                if (error) reject(error)
                resolve(token)
            }
        )
    });
};

module.exports = {
    authRequire: (req, res, next) => {
        const { token } = req.cookies
        try {
            if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized/Not token' })

            jwt.verify(token, TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
                if (err) return res.status(403).json({ message: "Invalid Token" })
                req.user = user

            })
            next()

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}

    register: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { username, email, password } = req.body;
            const aux = await auth.register(username, email, password)
            const token = await createAccesToken({ id: aux.id })
            res.cookie('token', token)
            res.status(200).json(aux)

        } catch (error) {
            res.status(409).json({ message: [error.message] })
        }
    },
    login: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { email, password } = req.body;
            const aux = await auth.login(email, password)
            const token = await createAccesToken({ id: aux.id })
            
            res.cookie('token', token);
            res.status(201).json(aux)
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(401).json({ error: error.message })
        }
    },

character.get('/', [validateToken.authRequire], [charHandler.getChar]);

http://localhost:3001/api/char/
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!